# Covering dough for the blessing on the dough offering

Tags: sources-mekorot, separating-challah

Before reciting the blessing "להפריש חלה..."  (or whatever other version) I've seen women remove the mandated size of dough and then **cover** the rest of the dough prior to reciting the blessing.

Is there any source for covering the main portion of the dough?

Comment: I've seen people cover the dough in a case where they are making a few batches. being that its in different bowls, they "combine" them by covering all with one cloth. otherwise they'd have to do hafrasha on each bowl separately. is this what you saw, or was it with only one bowl and they still covered it?

Comment: @Abochur It was only one bowl. But on the topic of your case, how can putting a cloth over one bowl constitute "combining"?

Comment: I'm not comfortable with the word offering in this context.

Comment: @Oliver that's a good question, i'm actually not sure. just mentioning what i've seen a few times

Comment: @Abochur OK, I appreciate it anyway.

Comment: @Heshy Have a better suggestion? "Separating", IMO, doesn't exactly capture the concept. Consecration? Just trying to appeal to all types of readers.

Comment: How about just challah?  If [Philip Blackman](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9675&st=&pgnum=393) couldn't come up with any clear definition in English shorter than "priest's share of the dough", I doubt you'll be able to beat him.  I guess you do "offer" it to the Kohen, but "offering" generally implies a korban, which this is most definitely not.  And considering it to be one is dangerous.

Comment: I think someone explained to me once that it is similar to the idea of covering the loaves of bread on Shabbat. The challah gets "embarassed" because it is not being blessed on first, but the blessing on wine precedes it. In a similar fashion, the larger batch of dough which is typically used for Shabbat challah also is "embarassed" when it is not used for the blessing for challah.

Comment: @Heshy If Philip Blackman is you're yard-stick then I guess there's nothing to debate. Aryeh Kaplan -who most would prob consider a credible authority- labels the biblical passage as the "Dough Offering" in The Living Torah (Num. 15:17). FWIW the *minha* brought by priests were not eaten by man and they are nevertheless labeled "offering".

Comment: @DanF Interesting. Wouldn't be surprised if that's where this "custom" originated from, albeit incongruously. If you can dig up an authoritative source I'd be grateful.

Comment: If Rabbi Kaplan does it I guess I can't complain.  What does being eaten have to do with an offering?  My point was that challah is burned to get rid of it, while korbanot are burned to fulfill the mitzva.

Comment: @heshy ואכלו אתם אשר כפר בהן giving parts to a priest to eat is definitely part of offering something to God. Is a Pesach not an offering since it is eaten?

Comment: Oliver, I think A bochur's idea could be that people know to cover multiple bowls and come to cover even only one since they don't fully understand the reason